# Is over charging the phone while using headset risky

Tags: power, battery-charging, heat, mobile

I recently came across a post in social network which was claiming to be a news about a girl getting electrocuted during her sleep with her headsets connected to the mobile and the mobile being connected to a charger.

Leaving aside the authenticity of the news, I was wondering whether there is any possibility of such an incident, considering even the rarest of the rarest scenarios.

Comment: To the downvoter: would you like to explain the downvote? Safety regulations compliance and failure modes *are* part of electronic design.

Comment: I feel as though the down voter needs to reconsider why they down voted. I'm guessing they down voted this because they considered it a ridiculous question but is in fact a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you say "considering even the rarest of the rarest scenarios" and this opens a big can of worms. I assume you don't want us to give borderline movie-like scenarios (e.g. the girl was sleeping on a water mattress and she had so sharp fingernails that she cut into the mattress spilling the water all over the place, including AC wall socket, etc..).

If we consider only *plausible* worst case scenarios, the answer may be *yes*, but it's indeed a very unlikely scenario. If it really happened it is probably due to a failure in the charger that triggered a nasty chain of events.

The charger must convert AC mains voltage to the smallish ~5V required to power modern phones, therefore any sensible designer should have designed it to have reasonable isolation between the parts connected to mains and the low voltage circuits. Usually the isolation measures must meet some safety standard for the country where the charger is sold. These requirements are not the most strict for these household appliances, because they are not intended to regulate devices that are ultimately connected to human body.

Medical equipment, for example an electrocardiograph, must meet much more stringent regulations, especially if powered from mains, because it is understood that in worst case scenarios there could be a person connected to the device and the risk of electrocution must be minimized in case of failures.

The very existence of these stricter regulations for medical equipment (even for non-professional ones, i.e. those that may be used at home by non-professionals) is a hint that the safety standards needed for common household appliances, such as a phone charger, are not deemed enough to protect human life in worst case scenarios where a person is connected in some way to the device.

Anyway, as I said at the beginning, it is really an unlikely scenario, unless:

- the charger was damaged or has been heavily abused, and/or
- the charger was a low-quality/non-original "cheap" one which wasn't designed with basic safety rules in mind (in some countries it is *illegal* to sell such things, but you always find cheap ones with counterfeited safety regulation approval marks).

If you want to see what kind of low-quality chargers are sold, this [EEVBlog video of a fake Apple charger disassembling](https://youtu.be/wi-b9k-0KfE) is interesting!

After a bit of googling, [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2677555/Teenager-suffers-electric-shock-using-faulty-USB-charger.html) and [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/australiaandthepacific/australia/10929662/Woman-in-Australia-killed-by-cheap-phone-charger.html) are two news articles referring to cases similar to the one you speak about. In both cases the culprit seems to be a faulty/not-compliant charger.

Comment: +1 well researched and in depth answer, also +1 for links to articles (sorry I can only give one +1)

Comment: I had asked for the rarest scenario to know for myself on to what extend the things should go wrong one after the other for such a mishap to occur. The answer is well researched and contains all the information that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No. The voltages involved in a phone are very low - 3 to 5 volts DC is the highest you're likely to see in most of the phone - and the output on the headpone jack is likewise low. There's also no path for power from the charger jack to the headphone jack.

The fact that you can touch your phone charger's plug and not feel anything is a pretty good demonstration of how harmless the voltages involved are.

Comment: You are assuming the case doesn't involve a charger failure.

Comment: Though this is the concept that I had in my mind too, as pointed out in the other answer, there were occurrences of  electrocution in the most weird way possible! A common man doesn't care about a counterfeit charger as long as it charges the phone. People are to be enlightened that the real risks of using counterfeit products are far bigger than one could imagine!