# Is it possible to use a wattmeter to switch a power outlet?

Tags: power, power-electronics

Can I use a wattmeter to switch a power outlet? My idea is to connect the wattmeter with a relay and when there is current the relay turns on like the thing in a master-slave power outlet. Is this possible?

Comment: I would advise being clearer if you do not want to collect downvotes... A wattmeter measures power, as its name suggests. It has nothing to do with switching on or off the outlet. What do you want your control signal to be?

Comment: @MisterMystere:Thank you. But I know what is a wattmeter. I want to know if possible and what are the details?

Comment: If you know a wattmeter is not meant to switch outlets, I still have no clue what you are trying to accomplish then, and I think I am not alone...

Comment: @MisterMyster:You can power a watch with some apples. I just ask the details. I look for serious people.

Comment: This made me spit up my coffee. Thanks for the morning laugh.

Comment: @ninehundredt:Whats so funny?

Comment: "You can power a watch with some apples. I just ask the details. I look for serious people." When serious people spend time trying to understand a poorly specified question just to help you in exchange for nothing, it would be a better tactic to show a little bit more respect. Try to understand *why* they are telling you to improve your question. Otherwise the only answer to your question "Is this possible?" will be "yes".

Comment: @LorenzoDonati After I commented I noticed three of my SO posts had been down-voted. Dealing with a real winner here.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati:I think most of the people here has understand my question very good. To me it's not possible atm. But if serious people is here they can explain it.

Comment: @ninehundredt:Yes, you need to accept answer, too. Not laughing at ohter people and spiting coffee!

Comment: @Phpdevpad At least you admit you're a douchebag.

Comment: @ninehundredt: Don't take it personal. *ÜP*ÜW

Comment: "But if serious people is here they can explain it." Sure they *can*, the real question is whether they *will* and *why*.

Comment: @ninehundredt: And your website in your profile doesn't work!

Comment: Ehm, why build such a device when there are products for sale that do this already: http://www.clasohlson.com/uk/Master-Slave-Extension-Lead/18-2124  This switches on the other sockets when the device on the first socket is switched on. Is this what you want ??

Comment: @ninehundredt: although you made my day, let's no get carried away. Phpdevpad: life lesson, when people do not understand you, your need to first assume YOU did not make that clear enough. Here, you need to clarify EXACTLY what you need to accomplish. Though there is now an answer, I'm pretty sure no one knows for sure what your goal is.

Comment: The goal is to receicle a wattmeter and a relay. A master-slave is expensive.

Comment: $20 for a master slave power strip is really not expensive compared to the components and time you would need to build this safely.

Comment: @Phpdevpad: if that is realy the goal it is surely possible, but it will cost you much more than a $20 master-slave strip, it will take quite a lot of time, and it involves some serious risk. Which is the one-line summary of my answer that you don't seem to like.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen:I am a new to this but I am interested in the shunt of the wattmeter. It seems to a resistor? Isn't there a circuit when there is current it can deliver 12 volts or less?

Comment: Yes, it is probably a resistor. No, it probably won't provide a voltage that is usefull to you (too small and varying with the current), and it can even be deep inside a specialised chip.

Answer (score 6):

```
"Is it possible to use a wattmeter to switch a power outlet?"
```

Yes, in the same sense that you can use a bike to build a boat.

```
"Can I use a wattmeter to switch a power outlet?"
```

I dunno what *you* can, that is up to you to decide. I probably could, but I see no reason to do so, because there are much easier ways. Including buying a master/slave power strip.

```
"My idea is to connect the wattmeter with a relay ..."
```

But how would you do that? I know wattmeters that are purely mechanical, I can't imagine how I would (easily) connect a relay to such a device.

The other type are the wall-wart like thingies that you plug in a socket and you plug your power-consuming device into the wattmeter. These types contain a few buttons, microcontroller of some sort, and an LCD display. Conceivably you could re-purpose the sensing circuit, or re-program the microcontroller, or interface to the LCD signals. All possible in theory, but a total waste of time in practice.

Re-purpsosing the sense circuit would make the most sense. But don't mess with mains-connected circuitry unless you realy know what you are doing. Or should I rather say: by all means do so and apply for a Darwin award?

Comment: +1 for the darwin award, and having made me understand what the OP might have wanted.

Comment: Questions are never stupid. Did you forget that? It seems to me you know your way but IMO this is the most arrogant and bored answer ever!! With 52 years you may have a secure life but you never know! Glad you take your time and answer it. Seems really funny and also you get upvotess.

Comment: @Phpdevpad As I've already pointed out in another comment, if you really want a meaningful answer, you should provide enough context. If expert people tell you your question doesn't provide enough information, please try to understand that the probability they're right is fairly high. Your question, as it stands, shows that you have little expertise in the electrical/electronics engineering field: I may be wrong, but if I am this is a clear indication that you didn't show enough effort! For a person with moderately high reputation on SO I guess you know the rules and the etiquette on SE sites!

Comment: @Phpdevpad Moreover, I have an issue with your attitude. You come here asking (demanding?) for help, you don't provide positive feedback, you don't try to understand the rules of this community, you insinuate people are not serious or say they are arrogant. Before accusing people of something have you at least tried to see if they did the same in other contexts? In particular Wouter is one of the most reputable member of EE.SE and very kind to anyone. If Jon Skeet on SO did answer in such a tone what would you think? Is Jon Skeet right and you provided poor information or vice versa?

Comment: @Phpdevpad by the way, just to be clear: some rash comments you have received, culminating with the ironic "Darwin award", is because some of us become easily upset by people asking for dangerous things and not listening to advice. EE is not software engineering. Mains can kill you very easily if you don't know what you are doing. ...

Comment: @Phpdevpad ... I have the impression that the widespread diffusion of low-voltage, low-power cheap MCU development boards has created a belief that electronics is all Arduino and the like. Electronics stuff can kill you! A PC power supply disconnected from mains can kill you if you mess with it inappropriately. Even a badly designed cheap phone charger can kill you (see [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/176560/29434)).

Comment: @LorenzoDonati:Teaching is funny, isn't it? It makes a living. I am particular interested in the shunt of the wattmeter. Can this be exploited?

Comment: @Phdevpad: I never said your question is stupid, but it is incomplete (you never stated the circustamces in which the relay should trigger), and you seem to make assumptions that are wrong (it would be usefull to re-purpose a wattemeter, and possible is the same as 'I can do it'). If you don't like to be told such things don't ask. And you might classify my answer as 'most arrogant and bored ever' (thanks for the praise), but you could think about whether it is to the point and correct. If it fails on those aspects you please let us know.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen:I don't believe you. And others had clearly stated in the comment what they think of my question. I have told before that I am looking for serious answer! Excuse me when I am not knowing each and anybody here and even then I don't mind?! Do you mind if s/b is more powerful then you?

Comment: 1) We are not in the believing buisiness here, we deal infacts, or lacking facts in opinions based in solid experience. 2) I don't get how 'what others said about your question' bears on how you respond to my answer. 3) You don't have to *know* everyone here (I don't think I realy know anyone here), but you can sure read the signatures. 4) I have no idea what s/b is or what his power or thoughness is. 5) By now you could have noticed that your qustion lacks some details, why not fill them in, so you might get an answer you like better than mine?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen:I am not sure what you mean with "business"? I already wrote the thing is to save money, i.e. fully use some spare parts here. 2nd. I wrote I am interested in the SHUNT and maybe it or the thing can deliver 12Volt. If I am expert I wouldn't ask and THAT I also wrote when I say "Questions are never stupid - its the answer that is stupid".

Comment: You said "I don't believe you", which is irrelevant: if you have a *reason* not to beleieve me, state what you don't believe and the reason. If you reason is to save money, and we say that this approach does not save money, why not take that as an answer? And it is good practice to update your answer instead of relying on readers to go through all the comments. But back to Q&A: is there anything factual in my answer that you don't agree with, or want to be clarified?

Comment: @Phpdevpad I won't reply to your childish provocations. Instead, I'll point out that if you used a fraction of the time you used to reply to comments to actually give us more information (what kind of wattmeter or relay, their specifications, photos or whatever) you could have had already what you say you want here. Your behavior here is borderline trollish, so I'm quitting. ***Don't feed the trolls***